# Minimum permissions on host for Register-PSSessionConfiguration RunAsCredential

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, winrm

I have a server hosting a powershell constrained endpoint, the endpoint is run as a service account (OurDomain\DoTransfer). This approach was chosen because the functions within the endpoint need permissions to read\write various remote file shares and local directories. And we did not wish to grant these elevated permissions to the users that would call the endpoint.

During development we added DoTransfer to the local admin group on the server hosting the endpoint and everything worked fine.

Now as part of hardening the endpoint to keep our security team happy I am trying to find the minimum permissions (on the host server) for DoTransfer to run the endpoint.

First I tried to take DoTransfer out of local\admins (so not in any local group), then call a test function via Invoke-Command. This through an access denied exception from import-module (the endpoint calls import-module to load a custom module which contains our code).

2nd I added DoTransfer to local\users and repeated the test which also failed with access denied for import-module.

3rd I added the DoTransfer back into local\admins and the test worked fine.

So does anyone know the minimum permissions DoTransfer needs to run the constrained endpoint on the host server?

Comment: if the code inside your function needs admin privilege , you have to add to admin group itself.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the service account (OurDomain\DoTransfer) did not require addition to any local groups.
The problem was DoTransfer required read\execute permissions on the folder containing the PowerShell Module backing the Constrained EndPoint